# How do I keep the parent list item highlighted with a background colour while any of it's child list items are clicked in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

Actually i have a list view when I click on the parent list view item i am getting dialog box with child list as same of parent list . then how can i highlight the background colour of parent item by clicking child item by using two diff  adapters for two list views.how can it possible.

activity:

> listView1.setAdapter(adapter);
>       adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
>       listView1.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
>
> ```
>     @Override
>     public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
>                                    int position, long id) {
>         // TODO Auto-generated method stub
>         newListitems2.clear();
>         newListitems2.addAll(itemsList1);
>
>         // ArrayList newListitems2 = new ArrayList();
>         //newListitems2.add(itemsList1);
>         dialog = new Dialog(PendingOrdersActitvity.this);
>         dialog.setContentView(R.layout.itembumping);
>         dialog.show();
>
>         listView1.setTag(position);
>         list1 = (ListView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.list1);
>
>         ItemBumpingAdapter adapter2 = new ItemBumpingAdapter(PendingOrdersActitvity.this, newListitems2);
>         list1.setAdapter(adapter2);
>
>
>         Button okButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.ok1);
>         okButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
>
>             @Override
>             public void onClick(View v) {
>
>                 dialog.dismiss();
>
>             }
>         });
>         Button cancelButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.Cancel1);
>         cancelButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
>
>             @Override
>             public void onClick(View v) {
>                 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
>                 dialog.dismiss();
>             }
>
>
>         });
>         return true;
>
>     }
> });
> ```

adapter for parent list:

> public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
>   { // TODO Auto-generated method stub
>
> ```
> ViewHolder holder;
> String item = null, qty = null;
> if (convertView == null) {
>     holder = new ViewHolder();
>     convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.itembumpingadapter, null);
>     holder.qty = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.qty);
>     holder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item);
>     holder.childText = (TextView) convertView
>             .findViewById(R.id.childitem);
>     holder.qtyChild = (TextView) convertView
>             .findViewById(R.id.qtychild);
>     holder.checkbox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.chckbox1);
>     convertView.setTag(holder);
>
> } else {
>
>     holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
> }
> parentobjid = newListitems.get(position).getParentobjectid();
> if (!parentobjid.isEmpty()) {
>     holder.name.setText("   " + newListitems.get(position).getItemnNameDisplay());
>     holder.name.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#CC0000"));
>     holder.qty.setText("      " + String.valueOf(newListitems.get(position)
>             .getQuantityDisplay()));
>     holder.qty.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#CC0000"));
> } else {
>     holder.name.setText(newListitems.get(position).getItemnNameDisplay());
>     holder.qty.setText(String.valueOf(newListitems.get(position).getQuantityDisplay()));
>     holder.name.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
> }
>
> return convertView; }
> ```

child list adapter:

> if (convertView == null) {
>
> ```
>     holder = new ViewHolder();
>     convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.itembumpingadapter, null);
>     holder.qty = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.qty);
>     holder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item);
>     holder.childText = (TextView) convertView
>             .findViewById(R.id.childitem);
>     holder.qtyChild = (TextView) convertView
>             .findViewById(R.id.qtychild);
>     holder.checkbox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.chckbox1);
>     convertView.setTag(holder);
> } else {
>     holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
> }
> parentobjid = newListitems.get(position).getParentobjectid();
> if (!parentobjid.isEmpty()) {
>     holder.name.setText(" " + newListitems.get(position).getItemnNameDisplay());
>     holder.name.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#CC0000"));
>     holder.qty.setText(" " + String.valueOf(newListitems.get(position).getQuantityDisplay()));
>     holder.qty.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#CC0000"));
> } else {
>     holder.name.setText(newListitems.get(position).getItemnNameDisplay());
>     holder.qty.setText(String.valueOf(newListitems.get(position).getQuantityDisplay()));
>     holder.name.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
>     holder.qty.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
>     holder.checkbox.setChecked(false);
>
>     holder.checkbox.setTag(position);
>     holder.checkbox.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
>         @Override
>         public void onClick(View v) {
>             // TODO Auto-generated method stub
>             int pos = (Integer) v.getTag();//Cast object to integer
>             newListitems.get(pos).setChecked(!newListitems.get(pos).isChecked());
>         }
>     });
>     if (newListitems.get(position).isChecked()) {
>         holder.name.setEnabled(true);
>         holder.name.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#DCDBDB"));
>
>     } else {
>         holder.name.setEnabled(false);
>     }
> }
> return convertView;
> ```

Comment: Can You Post Your Code or Explain In detail

Comment: i will post the code

Comment: i edited code @Aditya please see it